# How is right to close and "destroy" an object in Java

Tags: java

I have a map

```
public class MyMap implements Map<String,String>
```

It does some stuff in DB and it should do one of the following *destroy* methods:

1. If garbage collector destroyed myMap without `close()` than it should execute `clear()` method
2. If object destroys after `close()`, than all data saves in DB

It should work like FileWriter. If you close stream - data saves, if you don't - you lose :(

What should I use? `finalize()` , simply implement `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable` or something different?

Comment: Make it `AutoCloseable()`, so you can use it in try-with-resources, but why the `clear()`on GC? If you do nothing GC will clear all its fields anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`finalize()` is [deprecated since Java 9](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/why-not-to-use-finalize-method-in-java/amp/). It may not be called if the VM exits: if you call [`Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#runFinalizersOnExit(boolean)) it will be executed (but there are other problems with this).

Instead you should implement `AutoClosable`.

This allows to automatically close the `Map` with a `try-with-resources`.

You can also `close()` the `FileWriter` in your `close()` method as `FileWriter` implements `Closeable`(even `AutoCloseable`) too.

If you want to, you can override the `finalize()` method as a backup in case the closing did not work correctly but take care of the performance problems and the following as my source states:

> - Always call `super.finalize()` in your `finalize()` method.
> - Do not put time critical application logic in `finalize()`, seeing its unpredictability.
> - Do not use `Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit(true);` as it can put your system in danger.

- Catch and log exceptions by yourself as the system will ignore them.